# Issues with CSS Grid and Media Queries (HELP!)

Tags: html, css

my very last media query "@media (max-width: 400px)" doesn't change from the second media query "@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 1024px)". I want to change the number of columns for aside #outer from 4 to 2 and the number of columns for section #section from 2 to 1. How can I get it work without affecting the other media queries?

```
    @media (min-width: 1025px) {
        main {
            grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
            grid-template-areas: 
            "header header header header"
            "article article article aside"
            "section section section aside"
            "footer footer footer footer"
            ;
        }

        aside #outer {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-template-areas: 
        "item1 item2"
        "item3 item4"
        "item5 item6"
        ; 
        grid-gap: 15px 0px;
    }

    section #section {
        padding: 15px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-template-areas:
        "section1 section2"
        "section3 section4"
        ;
        grid-gap: 15px 15px;
    }
    }

    @media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
        aside #outer {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
            grid-template-areas: 
            "item1 item2 item3 item4"
            "item5 item6"
            ;
            grid-gap: 15px 15px;
            margin: 15px;
        ;
        }

        main {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
            grid-template-rows: auto;
            grid-template-areas: 
            "header"
            "article"
            "section"
            "aside"
            "footer"
            ;
            grid-gap: 10px;
        }

        section #section {
        padding: 15px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-template-areas:
        "section1 section2"
        "section3 section4"
        ;
        grid-gap: 15px 15px;
    }

    }

    @media (max-width: 400px) {
        main {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
            grid-template-areas: 
            "header"
            "article"
            "section"
            "aside"
            "footer"
            ;
            grid-gap: 10px;
        }

        section #section {
        padding: 15px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
        grid-template-areas:
        "section1"
        "section2"
        "section3"
        "section4"
        ;
        grid-gap: 15px 15px;
        }

        aside #outer {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            grid-template-areas: 
            "item1 item2"
            "item3 item4"
            "item5 item6"
            ;
            grid-gap: 15px 15px;
            margin: 15px;
        ;
        }

    }
```

I would appreciate anyone's ideas :)

Comment: Maybe the extra `;` after the last `margin: 15px` in your media query. Also, you're better off not even having the `max-width` media query. Take all of the styles out of that, put them at the top of your CSS document and use media queries to override those values. In fact, I would reorder your media queries - move the 400px and down out of the query and to the top, followed by the 401-1024 and then the 1025 and up.

Comment: getting rid of the extra ; still doesn't work.. Also, I have to use max-width specifically for my assignment. I changed the order of my media queries as you said though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was wrong with the media queries. It was just the size of the window was not small enough. It did work when I changed to mobile view.